# Accessing JSON with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

So I got the following JSON that I get from doing a HTML Request:

```
{ "cities": [ { "plz": "91443", "name": "Scheinfeld" }, { "plz": "91448", "name": "Emskirchen" } ] }
```

I am saving this JSON in the following variable:

```js
json = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(xhr.responseText));
console.log(json.cities[0].plz);
```

However I get the following error message:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange"
```

So it seems like trying to access plz with `json.cities[0].plz` is not the correct way.
So how do I do it right?

Comment: may I edit your question to create a [StackSnippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)
?

Comment: why are you parsing it after you stringily it, you do it then undo it

Comment: well my teacher told me in class that we have to stringily and then parse it to make a deep copy. it didnt make sense to me neither

Comment: "_my teacher told me_" - Using a "JSON.parse-then-stringify" approach is one technique for creating a deep copy of a JS object - if a deep copy is what you need. Side note: there are some [limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122704/12567365) to that approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `parse` only

```
json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```